# Other view is not loading in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using below code in implementation file. The issue is when I click on a row it does not take me to another view?

please help

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 3;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Vehicle List %d", [indexPath row]+1];

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (self.vehic == nil) {
    Vehicle *vehicle = [[Vehicle alloc] initWithNibName:@"Vehicle" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    self.vehic = vehicle;
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.vehic animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: if you put a NSLog inside `didSelectRow...` that code get executed? And Vehicle is UIViewController subclass?

Comment: Give some info About vehic and Vehicle Objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For going to another View you should handle this method Correctly :-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// on click on any row now it will go to Another View, let the other view be SecondViewController's View

SecondViewController *viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES]; 

}
```

That's all. If you face any problem then tell me. :)

Comment: ! Thanks bro, you have solved my issue. Now tell me if each row represents different data then how to do it...

Comment: See dude cellForRowAtIndexPath method Invokes for Every Row in a table automatically, you do one thing, as soon as you TAP on any row Take the corresponding data in an array of APPDELEGATE class in the didSelectRow method, and go the Next ViewController. Now in cellForRowPathAtIndex set like this :-  [cell.textLable.text:YourArray ObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]